# In Debian-based script: how to determine if kernel changed and needs reboot?

Tags: debian, scripting, kernel, upgrade, reboot

How can we (more) easily determine if a kernel-change-reboot is required in Debian, other than [doing this](https://serverfault.com/a/474596/104173) in a script (which is a bit cumbersome)?

Ubuntu has [`/var/run/reboot-required`](https://serverfault.com/a/92939/104173) and per our experience it works well. However, thus far Debian (at least in Buster, 10.6) does not. Some package(s) might have done this in the past ([prior to Debian Jessie](https://serverfault.com/questions/92932/how-does-ubuntu-keep-track-of-the-system-restart-required-flag-in-motd/92939#comment941989_92939)) and were replaced thigns that try/claim to do it today, but we've seen nothing work (in 10.6). Details below.

Things we've tried (in Debian 10.6) with no success:

1. [checkrestart](https://serverfault.com/a/667264/104173) (no simple binary state report for kernel boot)
2. [needrestart](https://serverfault.com/questions/667076/how-can-i-know-if-reboot-is-required-after-update#comment892628_667264) (same problem as #1)
3. Despite https://serverfault.com/a/667082/104173 claiming so, `/var/run/reboot-required.pkgs` has not yet been visible on our Debian 10.6 system (after a kernel upgrade).
4. [reboot-notifier](https://serverfault.com/questions/92932/how-does-ubuntu-keep-track-of-the-system-restart-required-flag-in-motd/92939#comment941989_92939) does not seem to offer anything that works.
5. [`lsof | grep lib | grep DEL`](https://serverfault.com/a/667082/104173) does not (yet) seem to provide what we need.

"Nagios output mode" for some of the above options do not (yet) seem easily parsable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about checking the return code? `needrestart -k -p > /dev/null; echo $?` gives `0` for an up-to-date kernel, and `2` if the running kernel is not the expected one.

Comment: `-k`, first time I'm seeing this option, thanks. I'll try it out. Question: is there an authoritative reference somewhere that specifies these `0` and `2` values, to authoritatively confirm the above translations?  (eg: is this part of the Nagios definition for parsing return codes, per `-p`?  @gf_ )

Comment: @JohnnyUtahh `0` maps to `OK`, while `2` maps to `Critical`, as per https://nagios-plugins.org/doc/guidelines.html#AEN78. Also, these return codes are configurable, as per https://github.com/liske/needrestart/blob/debian-buster/ex/needrestart.conf#L202-L214.

Comment: We ran some tests and `needrestart` appears (in a small # of test scenarios) to behave as specified above. Very cool. However: `needrestart` is very noisy and/or unacceptably intrusive in it's default behavior, even when used as above (as part of a script). Here's our config file changes (from `/etc/needrestart/needrestart.conf`'s defaults) to get it to "keep quiet" and/or not get in our way (these changes were educated guesses on our part), per Debian 10.6 / `needrestart` v3.4 (`etckeeper` change tracking):  https://imgur.com/a/WtgpmgU

Comment: All in all: we still do not understand why Debian needs to make a reboot-for-kernel-upgrade signal so bloody, freagin' hard. `/var/run/reboot-required` works wonderfully in Ubuntu; can anybody offer or speculate why has it not yet been adopted in Debian?

Comment: Finally: big big thanks @gf_ for providing the above references and details. Super appreciated.